# Grunt JS: Name output files using NPM version in package.json

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I want to use `npm` version from `package.json` file to name output (generate files) in Grunt tasks.

The following example will make it more clear:
package.json file
`{
  "name": "my Project",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "dependencies": {},
  ......
}`

Output that i want to reach is:
`mycssfile.1.0.6.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `require` to parse json.
`var npmVersion = require('./package.json').version;`
And then use this var, something like:
`'<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.<%= npmVersion %>.css'`

Answer (score 1):

Just `require` the json file and it you get it parsed:

```
var version = require('./something/package.json').version
```